# How can i design the cell dynamic in UITableView iPhone?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have designed my `UITableViewCell` in iPhone. Unfortunately I need to redesign the Cell. I will explain my problem. My previous/current cell design like below:

```
Header(11.1.2012) //single row
event1
time1
Header(12.1.2012) //single row
event1
time1
Header(13.1.2012) //single row
event1
time1
Header(13.1.2012) //single row
event2
time2
Header(13.1.2012) //single row
event3
time3
```

Header(11.1.2012)
event1 is a singel row in a TableView cell. But, i need to change the design like this:

```
Header(11.1.2012) //single row
event1
time1
Header(12.1.2012) //single row 
event1
time1
Header(13.1.2012) //single row
event1
time1
event2
time2
event3
time3
```

I'm really confused as to how to do this? Can anyone please suggest any ideas and sample code to do like this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


        UIView *dateView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
        dateView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transactionHeader.png"]];

        UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 30)];
        headerLabel.tag = 100;
        headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [dateView addSubview: headerLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:dateView]; 

        UILabel *eventLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 300, 25)];
        eventLabel.tag = 101;
        eventLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        eventLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
        eventLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        eventLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: eventLabel];

        UILabel *timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 55, 300, 25)];
        timeLabel.tag = 102;
        timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
        timeLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: timeLabel]; 
    }

    UILabel * headerLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    headerLabel.text = [headerDateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *eventLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    eventLabel.text = [eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel * timeLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
    timeLabel.text = [timeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Currently am using this code in my project. What i need to change? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexCoplan I have attached my current code. I want to alter the code for my new row design. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Thanks to all for answering and viewing my question. I have got the idea and solved the problem. I have added Header for each row and removed the header where the data returns null.
Now, it is working very well in my app. Once again i thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the headers be section headers instead of part of the cell, and the event and time as the table cells. Otherwise you will need will need to extend UITableViewCell for a custom cell.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *dateView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
    dateView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transactionHeader.png"]];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 30)];
    headerLabel.tag = 100;
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [dateView addSubview: headerLabel];
    return dateView;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        ...
    }
    ...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"event1";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"time1";
    return cell;
}
```